# Pull data from two separate SQL tables based on a JOIN but that uses a column not in the JOIN or the SELECT

Tags: sqlite, join, union

This is based on [a Khan Academy course](https://www.khanacademy.org/computer-programming/sql-join-on-tables/5409956539006976). I have 2 SQLite tables:

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (id STRING PRIMARY KEY, charge_id TEXT, amount INTEGER, currency INTEGER, country STRING);
INSERT INTO table1 
(     id, charge_id, amount, currency, country) VALUES 
('0xb01',     '0x1',   2000,    'USD',   'USA'),
('0x0a1',     '0x1',    500,    'USD',   'USA'),
('0x0c1',     '0x1',   1000,    'CAD',   'USA'),
('0xs31',     '0x4',   1000,    'YEN',    'CA');

CREATE TABLE table2 (id STRING PRIMARY KEY, charge_id TEXT, value VARIABLE);
INSERT INTO table2 
(     id, charge_id, value            ) VALUES 
('0x34s',     '0x1', '123 main street'),
('0x3ze',     '0x1', 'merchant-id-001'),
('0x3w2',     '0x2', 'zip-code-90210' ),
('0x35k',     '0x2', 'merchant-id-002');
```

I would SELECT the amount, currency and country from table 1 (Charges) and join with table 2 (Metadata) based on the id. Charges uses ID, while Metadata stores meta tags, with a unique identifier [id] equal to the charge [id] from Charges. I want to group the total amount, total currency for each merchant_id and only those charges that were made in the USA.

Step-by-step pseudo code:

(1) find all charges in the USA (Charges `country`)
(2) match all charge_ids from Charges (`id`) to charges in Metadata (`id`)
(3) separate each charge by the merchant_id (Metadata `value`)
(4) display the total amount, currency by merchant_id (`amount`, Charges `currency`, `value`)

This is a difficult because :

(1) I want to select from Charges and
(2) join to Metadata by the [id]
(3) but each Metadata record only has the charge_id and a metadata tag, which would match the merchant_id with the charge

The query result I would like is:

```
value (merchant id)   currency       total amount
merchant-id-001       usd            2500
merchant-id-001       cad            1000
merchant-id-002       yen             200
merchant-id-002       cad              50
```

Currently I have this query but it does not seem to be working:

```
select table1.amount, table1.currency, table1.country, count(*)
from  table1
LEFT JOIN  table1
UNION ALL
SELECT table2.value
FROM CHARGES_table2
LEFT JOIN table2
ON table1.id = table2.id
WHERE table1.country = 'USA'
GROUP BY table2.value
```

I am getting errors on union parameters: 2,1

Comment: Showing your sample table and data a `CREATE TABLE` and `INSERT` statements would make it a lot easier to work with...

Comment: What is `identifier` supposed to be? The leading `0x` makes it look like it's supposed to be a number in base 16, but then you have things like `0x3s1`. Plus it's not in your descriptions of the table layouts, just their contents (See previous comment).

Comment: The sample data you posted do not have a single id common in the 2 tables.

Comment: They share charge_ids across both tables

Comment: *I would SELECT the amount, currency and country from table 1 (charges) and join with table 2 based on the* **id**.Then why do you mention `id` when they both have columns `id`

Comment: Edit your question and explain what you want, and mention the correct column names.

Comment: "I am getting errors on union parameters:" Tell us exactly. Please in code questions give a [mcve]--cut & paste & runnable code; example input with desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & clear specification & explanation. That includes the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.)

Comment: Your problem is a syntax error. (You should first have shown as much as possible that the constituent subexpressions were OK.) Make it clear that your question is about that error & ask re your overall goal later in a new post. PS Why is that code in your question twice? Also now that you have given CREATEs & input data in tablular format (as you should, although it could be formatted more readably) the "Visually" section is not needed either. Please don't insert EDITs/UPDATEs, just make your post the best presentation as of right now.

Comment: I edited your post. Click on 'edited' to see the source. Read the edit help re formatting code & quotes in blocks & inline, re line breaks via two spaces at line end & re bulleted & numbered lists. But your text is garbled: you refer to tables & some columns by 2 names; you confuse column names & entity names & "identifier"/"id"/"ID"; your writing is unclear. PS  I added `change_id` in table1 VALUES--either it was missing or it did not belong in CREATE & VALUES--which is correct? You gave code that you did not run. This is why a [mcve] is required & why it must have been run & cut & pasted.

Comment: Please do not edit questions in a way that invalidates reasonable upvoted answers. You just rolled back to version 1--before my edits (that mostly just removed redundant text) & before your own changes--then you edited this down to where it does not contain a question. I have rolled this back to [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/56467923/5). If you don't like that, roll back again. But please just edit your text to get the column names correct in code & text & then "ask re your overall goal later in a new post". Which should be self-contained, not just a link, and ask a question.

Comment: [Change to question invalidates my answer, what to do?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/286803/266284)

Answer (score 1):

Read the grammar & other documentation for the expressions you are using. The arguments to UNION are two SELECTs & it can have a final ORDER BY. Here's the parse:

```
    select table1.amount, table1.currency, table1.country, count(*)
    from  table1
    LEFT JOIN  table1

UNION ALL

    SELECT table2.value
    FROM CHARGES_table2
    LEFT JOIN table2
    ON table1.id = table2.id
    WHERE table1.country = 'USA'
    GROUP BY table2.value
```

UNION is putting its arguments' rows into one table so it also requires that their columns agree in number & have compatible types. Here the numbers disagree.

There is no table1 in scope in the second SELECT so that is an error in isolation that is moot given the UNION.